# msdeploy.exe with runcommand: problem executing commands

Tags: msdeploy

I want to use msdeploy to start a batch file on my remote server.

Usage is like

```
msdeploy.exe -verb:sync -allowUntrusted:true -source:runCommand="c:/scripts/x.bat" -dest:auto,computerName=https://server:8172/msdeploy.axd?site=xxx,userName=xxx,password=xxx,authType=basic
```

The x.bat is executed on the remote server. One part of the x.bat is to delete a local file - that works. Then I want to kill a process on that remote server via "taskkill /FI "WindowTitle eq X" /f", but I get the message that no tasks are found.

When I run the x.bat on the remote server, the tasks are killed just fine...

Comment: I solved the problem with the taskkill - for some reason the window title filter did not work, but it worked by using the exe name instead.

Comment: The next problem is: I want to start an exe file in the batch file using  start "title" job.exe, but that does not work either

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem by using schstart to schedule a task which runs one minute later the batch file

Answer (score 0):

according to [`taskkill`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/taskkill) documentation:

> Remarks:
>   The WINDOWTITLE and STATUS filters are not supported when a remote system is specified.

according to [start](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/start) documentation:

> Title: Specifies the title to display in the Command Prompt window title bar.

So this title is for cmd window itself not job.exe